# How to get foreground and background colors of textbox for further usage in Color Picker?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit

Foreground and Background properties are of Brush type. How to get Color for further usage in Color Picker?

I pass Foreground and Background to c-tor of a properties window like this:

```
private void Menu_Properties_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PropertiesDialog propDialog = new PropertiesDialog(TbTimer.Foreground, TimerPanel.Background);
    if (propDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        //set color to TbTimer textbox and TimerPanel WrapPanel
    }
}
```

`TbTimer` is TextBox, `TimerPanel` is WrapPanel.

This is properties window c-tor:

```
public PropertiesDialog(Brush foreground, Brush background)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    FontColorPicker.SelectedColor = foreground; //Compilation error
    BgColorPicker.SelectedColor = background; //Compilation error
}
```

Here I get `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Media.Brush' to 'System.Windows.Media.Color'`.

How to get brushes color?

Comment: This question does not make any sense what so ever, what has the textbox got to do with it?

Comment: The content of textbox like foreground and background are customizable by user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the `Background` property of an element in XAML to something like "Red", a type converter converts the string "Red" into a `SolidColorBrush` object whose `Color` property is set to the appropriate colour.

So this:

```
<TextBlock Background="Red" />
```

is equivalent to this:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" />
    </TextBlock.Background>
</TextBlock>
```

`SolidColorBrush` is the only brush type that has a single "colour". Other brush types may have more than one colour, or may not really represent "colour" at all (such as a `DrawingBrush` or `VisualBrush` for example).

If you want your dialog's constructor to take `Brush` objects as parameters but also want to deal with them as single colours, then you will need to cast them as `SolidColorBrush` objects as per @BenjaminPaul's answer. The type of the brush may actually be different of course, so an explicit cast would fail with an exception.

The best you can do is something like this:

```
public PropertiesDialog(Brush foreground, Brush background)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var solidForeground = foreground as SolidColorBrush;
    var solidBackground = background as SolidColorBrush;

    if (solidForeground == null || solidBackground == null)
    {
        // One or both of the brushes does not have a
        // single solid colour; what you do here is up to you
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    FontColorPicker.SelectedColor = solidForeground.Color;
    BgColorPicker.SelectedColor = solidBackground.Color;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thanks for a thorough answer.

Answer (score 0):

simpy alter your method signature:

```
public PropertiesDialog(System.Windows.Media.Color foreground, System.Windows.Media.Color background)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    FontColorPicker.SelectedColor = foreground; 
    BgColorPicker.SelectedColor = background; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SelectedColour is expecting the System.Windows.Media.Color type however you are attempting to assign a brush... try casting as follows.

```
public PropertiesDialog(Brush foreground, Brush background)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    FontColorPicker.SelectedColor = ((SolidColorBrush)foreground).Color;
    BgColorPicker.SelectedColor = ((SolidColorBrush)background).Color; 
}
```